# qmake: make uninstall tries to remove system folders containing files installed with INSTALLS

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, qmake

This is my `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = myapp
INCLUDEPATH += .

win32 {
    RC_FILE = win32/myapp.rc
}

unix {
    target.path = /usr/share/myapp/
    shortcutfiles.files += unix/myapp.desktop
    shortcutfiles.path = /usr/share/applications/
    data.files += unix/myapp.png
    data.path = /usr/share/pixmaps/
    INSTALLS += target
    INSTALLS += shortcutfiles
    INSTALLS += data
}

SOURCES += myapp.cpp
QT += webkitwidgets

RESOURCES += \
    myapp.qrc
```

Under linux, the `make uninstall` command, while removing the actual installed files and folder, tries to remove the `/usr/share/applications/` and `/usr/share/pixmaps/` folders (with `rmdir`); and because they are not empty folders it fails with error code 1 (ignored actually).

How to modify my `.pro` file to prevent `make uninstall` from trying to remove those system folders?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't.  This is how it should be.

Comment: I thought so too.. :-)

Comment: You specify the path as /usr/share/applications rather than /usr/share/applications/Unix ... Why?

Comment: Well... It's the folder for shortcut files in linux... (the shortcut file `myapp.desktop` will be placed in the `/usr/share/applications/` folder)